# Quality of ListPlot Output

Tags: plotting

I am plotting a dataset using the following code

```
ListPlot[dataset, PlotStyle -> Black, Frame -> False, Axes -> True, 
         AspectRatio -> 1, PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 3}]
```

This is the output I obtain.

[image]

Clearly the quality is quite bad. How can I improve the resolution? I tried to play around with the PlotMarkers. But nothing worked so far.

PS: I can provide the csv file if needed.

Comment: @Nasser I tried `PerformacneGoal->Quality` but it didn't change anything, neither did trying different `Mesh` options.

Comment: To smooth a `ListPlot` you should smooth the data.

Comment: Not to be a smarty pants, but what is wrong with the quality? What aspects are you looking to change?  Is it the pixelization on the curved parts of the plot or something else?

Comment: @RudyPotter Yes, it's the pixelation on the curved parts. The csv dataset consists of 20k points calculated in matlab. When I plot it there, I get a smooth curve. However, I need this curve on top of a RegionPlot in Mathematica, where I get this pixelization.

Comment: @BobHanlon could you please explain what you mean by that?

Comment: A `ListPlot` will put the marker at the coordinates of each point. If the points don't form a smooth curve, there are no options that will smooth the plot. The underlying data would have to be smoothed to result in a smooth plot.

Comment: @BobHanlon I am still not sure what you mean by that. When I plot the dataset in R or Matlab it forms a smooth curve. I downsampled the data, but that did not help.

Comment: Provide a link to the data.

Answer (score 2):

If one don't want to use `Joined->True` and `InterpolationOrder -> 3` in `ListPlot`, we can also use `Interpolation` directly.

```
Clear[dataset, reg, pts, f];
dataset = 
  Table[(2 + 2/3.5 Sin[3 t])*RotationMatrix[t] . {1, 0}, {t, 0, 2 Pi, 
    0.15}];
dataset = RandomSample[dataset, Length@dataset];
reg = ReconstructionMesh[dataset];
pts = Append[#, First@#] &@MeshPrimitives[reg, 1][[;; , 1, 1]];
plot1 = ListPlot[pts, PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 3}, 
   AspectRatio -> Automatic];
f = Interpolation /@ Transpose@pts;
plot2 = ListPlot[Table[Through[f@t], {t, 1, Length@pts, .05}], 
   PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 3}, AspectRatio -> Automatic];
plot3 = ListPlot[Table[Through[f@t], {t, 1, Length@pts, .05}], 
   Joined -> True, AspectRatio -> Automatic];
plot4 = ParametricPlot[Through[f@t], {t, 1, Length@pts}];
GraphicsGrid[{{plot1, plot2}, {plot3, plot4}}]
```

[image]

Comment: I tried `Joined->True` and `InterpolationOrder->3` but nothing changed. I also downsized the dataset to 5000, 2000 and 1000 pts and it also did not improve the quality. And I cannot run your code. `ReconstructionMesh` is no command in my version 12.1 I guess.

Comment: @Squeezelemma Please provide your data!!! All of my codes work!!!